# IE8 Javascript: '2' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting a nonsensical error message in IE8, tell me that the constant '2' is null or not an object.  The line of code is:

```
if (! localtree[idx][2]) {
```

I also tried coding it like this:

```
if (localtree[idx][2] == 0) {
```

The value in the array at that location is always zero (for now).

How can IE8 think that the number 2 is null?  I'm mystified!

The exact error is:

```
Message: '2' is null or not an object
```

Has anyone seen this?

**EDIT :** This is a very misleading error message. See my answer below for what actually went wrong.

Comment: How are you initialising localtree?

Comment: What error does Firefox give for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very confusing error message.  It turned out that I was stepping one element beyond the end of the array.  'idx' was referencing a non-existent value that I was attempting to treat as an array reference (with the [2]).

Rather than telling me that '2' was null, it should have said that 'localtree[idx]' was null.

The root cause of this was that I had a trailing comma where I defined the array, leading to an extra, null value in the array.  In firefox, trailing commas are ignored (like in perl), but in IE, they are significant.

Comment: Ah, the classic trailing comma problem. And no, `localtree[idx]` is not `null`, because `localtree[idx][0]` and `…[1]` do exist (objects themselves *always* evaluate to `true`), but `…[2]` is. That said, I agree that the error message could be clearer. BTW, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) gives a warning message when you feed it an array with a trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

> the constant '2' is null or not an object
>
> ```
> if (! localtree[idx][2]) {
> ```

JavaScript doesn't have constants, at least not yet. And you aren't checking a number, but a member of an array, i.e.: the variable with index number `2` of object `localtree[idx]` (where `idx` must contain a string to refer to an object property or an index number to refer to an array).

Comment: Yes but the error message specifically says that '2' is the problem.  Also, '2' is a constant.